# Using php in html

Tags: php, html

I have login form and a database corresponding to it. I want to use else block to display  Invalid username/password after login here title. How to use else block of my php code in a html form somwhere

```
<?php

require "connect.inc.php";
if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password))
    {
        $query="SELECT id FROM sch_user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
        {
            $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($num_rows===1)
            {
                header("Location:index.html");
            }

?>   


<head>
    <title>Brilliant Educational Society</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="branch_login.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="container" border=0">
        <tr><td>
            <table id="title_container" border=0 width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:90px;"><div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg" style="height:70px;width:70px;margin-left: 10px;"></div></td>
                <td><div id="title" style="color:maroon"><b><i>Brilliant Educational Society</b></div></td></i>
                <td style="width:200px"><div id="contact">Contact 9030059263</div><br /><br />
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <tr><td>
            <table id="menu_container">
            <tr><td><ul id="menu">
                    <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="academics"><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
                    <li id="staff"><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                    <li id="about_us"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>
            <table id="login_form" border=0>
                <tr><td><label id="login_title">Login here</label><br />
<?php
                else
                {
                    echo 'Invalid Username/Password';
                }

            }                  
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'Please provide both Username and Password';
     }
}                
?>                    
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td><form action="branch_login.php" method="post"><br />
                    <label id="user">Username</label><input style="margin-left:20px" type="text" name="username" size="20"/><br /><br />
                    <label id="pass">Password</label><input style="margin-left:20px" type="password" name="password" size="20"/><br /><br />
                    <input style="margin-left:215px;background:orange;width:80px;height:30px;font-family: Times New Roman;font-size:20px" type="submit" value="Login >>"/> 
                </form></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using post variables in a SQL statement without checks? And are you storing passwords in plain text? Bad things are going to happen for sure. Use `PDO` statements and some hashing function (`MD5, SHA, ...`)

Comment: What if I entered `' OR 1=1--` into the login form ;-) Think about the resulting query that would be executed

Comment: i suggest you to read one or more php books/ebooks before doing any actual coding

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions as they are deprecated now, suggested by all, for any new development use PDO, PHP data objects instead, they are simple to use, have a look at 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: actually my question is - When I put my whole php block of code at one place, all are working fine but I want to write 'else block of Invalid Username/Password' after login here i.e., above the form, Even When I do it, all are working fine but html code is broken and page is not displaying properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require "connect.inc.php";
if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password))
    {
        $query="SELECT id FROM sch_user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
        {
            $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($num_rows===1)
            {
                header("Location:index.html");
            }

?>   


<head>
    <title>Brilliant Educational Society</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="branch_login.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="container" border=0">
        <tr><td>
            <table id="title_container" border=0 width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:90px;"><div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg" style="height:70px;width:70px;margin-left: 10px;"></div></td>
                <td><div id="title" style="color:maroon"><b><i>Brilliant Educational Society</b></div></td></i>
                <td style="width:200px"><div id="contact">Contact 9030059263</div><br /><br />
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <tr><td>
            <table id="menu_container">
            <tr><td><ul id="menu">
                    <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="academics"><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
                    <li id="staff"><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                    <li id="about_us"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
        <tr><td>
            <table id="login_form" border=0>
                <tr><td><label id="login_title">Login here</label><br /><td>
<?php
                else
                {
                    echo 'Invalid Username/Password';
                }

            }                  
     }
     else
     {
        echo 'Please provide both Username and Password';
     }
}                
?>                    
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td><form action="branch_login.php" method="post"><br />
                    <label id="user">Username</label><input style="margin-left:20px" type="text" name="username" size="20"/><br /><br />
                    <label id="pass">Password</label><input style="margin-left:20px" type="password" name="password" size="20"/><br /><br />
                    <input style="margin-left:215px;background:orange;width:80px;height:30px;font-family: Times New Roman;font-size:20px" type="submit" value="Login >>"/> 
                </form></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
```